# I am trying to plot a race time "01:23:22" on a chart with Flot and so i can compare over time

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

I am writing an App that tracks swimmers race results based on date and time

The data set will look similar to this (Date, RaceTime)

```
    var results = [
        ['12/01/2015', '02:05:00'],
        ['12/08/2015', '01:15:00'],
        ['12/15/2015', '04:20:00']
    ];
```

I am using the following code to try and plot it, but I cannot get accurate plots and tooltip is wrong.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

        var originalData = [
            ['12/01/2015', '02:05:00'],
            ['12/08/2015', '01:15:00'],
            ['12/15/2015', '04:20:00']
        ];

        var data = [];
        var test = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < originalData.length; i++) {
            var dataPoint = [];
            dataPoint.push((new Date(originalData[i][0])));

            var time = originalData[i][1].split(':');
            var hours = parseInt(time[0]);
            var minutes = parseInt(time[1]);
            var seconds = parseInt(time[2]);

            dataPoint.push(hours + minutes + seconds /60);

            data.push(dataPoint);

        }


        var options = {
            series: {
                lines: {
                    show: true
                },
                points: {
                    show: true
                }
            },
            xaxis: {
                mode: 'time',
                timeformat: "%0m/%0d %0H:%0M",
                tickSize: [5, 'week']
            },

            yaxis: {
                min: 0,
                max: 24
            },
            grid: {
                hoverable:true,
                clickable:true
            }
        };

        var plot = $.plot("#placeholder"
                ,[data], options);

        var previousPoint = null;
        $("#placeholder").bind("plothover", function (event, pos, item) {
            $("#x").text(pos.x.toFixed(2));
            $("#y").text(pos.y.toFixed(2));

            if (item) {
                if (previousPoint != item.datapoint) {
                    previousPoint = item.datapoint;

                    $("#tooltip").remove();
                    var x = item.datapoint[0].toFixed(2),
                            y = item.datapoint[1].toFixed(2)

                    showTooltip(item.pageX, item.pageY,
                            y);
                }
            }
            else {
                $("#tooltip").remove();
                previousPoint = null;
            }
        });

        function showTooltip(x, y, contents) {
            $('<div id="tooltip">' + contents + '</div>').css( {
                position: 'absolute',
                display: 'none',
                top: y + 5,
                left: x + 5,
                border: '1px solid #fdd',
                padding: '2px',
                'background-color': '#fee',
                opacity: 0.80
            }).appendTo("body").fadeIn(200);
        }
    });

</script>
```

My goal is to plot the 3 values so that I can see the differences in the swimmers times

The code

**dataPoint.push(hours + minutes + seconds /60);**

is messing things up and not working as I intended.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: if you want the times in minutes, you need `60*hours + minutes + seconds/60` (or in hours: `hours + minutes/60 + seconds/3600`)

Comment: Thanks. How can I show the original time  (01:23:23 for example ) string as a tooltip when hovering ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code `dataPoint.push(hours + minutes + seconds /60);` treats hours and minutes the same which leads to errors. If you want to display the race time in minutes, use `60*hours + minutes + seconds/60` (if you want it in hours use `hours + minutes/60 + seconds/3600`).

To get the original formatted race time back from the race time in minutes, use something like this:

```
function getFormattedTime(timeInMinutes) {
    var hours = Math.trunc(timeInMinutes / 60);
    var minutes = Math.trunc(timeInMinutes % 60);
    var seconds = Math.round(60 * (timeInMinutes - Math.round(timeInMinutes)));

    var result = hours.toString() + ':';
    result += (minutes < 10 ? '0' : '') + minutes.toString() + ':';
    result += (seconds < 10 ? '0' : '') + seconds.toString();

    return result;
}
```